# A weird bug encountered with scipy, any thought?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing an optimization project, and I encountered a very weird bug with scipy. After several times of execution of the objective function, its parameter vector magically becomes a 2-D array(but it is supposed to be a 1-D array all the time), without any explicit instruction.
Anyone ever encountered the same thing?
Is this possibly a scipy bug or should I double check my code again?

I mean, if there is something wrong in my code, I don't see any reason it happened after several iterations being properly executed

for each time the objective function is called, I print the x and its shape. This is the code inside the objective funtion

```
def objective(x, some, other, parameters..):

    print("current x",x)
    print("current x.shape",x.shape)

    some code here...


    score = calculate_objective_function(some_parameters_here...)
    return -score
```

And here is what happened

```
current x [-2322.83367669 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
0
current x [-2322.83367669 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
1
current x [-2321.83367669 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
2
current x [-2324.45171069 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
3
current x [-2322.83367669 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
4
current x [-2323.45171067 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
5
current x [-2322.45171069 13868.03814803     0.        ]
current x.shape (3,)
6
current x [[-2322.8237272  13868.03814803     0.        ]]
current x.shape (1, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/optimization_image.py", line 692, in <module>
    solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='Powell',args= additional_and_point_cloud, callback= callback_fun)
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 590, in minimize
    return _minimize_powell(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 2612, in _minimize_powell
    tol=xtol * 100)
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 2398, in _linesearch_powell
    alpha_min, fret, iter, num = brent(myfunc, full_output=1, tol=tol)
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 2109, in brent
    res = _minimize_scalar_brent(func, brack, args, **options)
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 2141, in _minimize_scalar_brent
    brent.optimize()
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1992, in optimize
    fu = func(*((u,) + self.args))      # calculate new output value
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 2397, in myfunc
    return func(p + alpha*xi)
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 326, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/home/mingzhe/PycharmProjects/ZebraFinder/venv/optimization_image.py", line 550, in objective
    centroid = image_coordinate_from_world_coordinate(np.array([x[0],x[1]]),scale_factor,min_point_world)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[the screenshot of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9odU.png)

**UPDATE : problem solved by the answer from @HYRY. My score calculation function returns a 1*1 numpy matrix rather than a scaler. After casting to float, it works as expected.**

Comment: Can you add the error and the code generating it?

Comment: yes @ladygremlin, I added the info

Comment: The title of the questions isn’t correct, can you change it something more appropriate?

Comment: Hi @iRohitBhatia, I understand that the title may not be accurate enough,  but the situation is so weird and I honestly don't know how to describe it properly. English is not my first language. Sorry for the confusion, and It would be great if you have any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the score value returned is not a scalar value, for example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

cnt = 0
def f(x):
    global cnt
    print(x.shape)
    cnt += 1
    if cnt < 10:
        return np.sum(x**2)
    else:
        e = np.full((1, 1), fill_value=np.sum(x**2))
        return e

optimize.minimize(f, [0, 0, 1], method="powell")
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  the score was calculated by numpy array multiplication, so it returned a 2D array [[score]] as the result. After casting to float, the code does work as expected. But would you mind to elaborate a little bit the reasoning behind?